# MVC ForgotPassword method not sending reset email

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have following GET and POST method in my AccountController:

```
// GET: /Account/ForgotPassword
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ForgotPassword
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
                if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
                {
                    // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
                    return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
                }

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                 string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
                 var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);     
                 await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
                return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

This uses the standard ForgotPassword method defined by Visual studio. I just put an actionlink on my login View like this:

```
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
                </p>
```

The problem is, I don't get a reset e-mail for a registered user after submitting the email I want to reset in the ForgotPassword view. Is there anything wrong in my code?

I have also configured the mail settings in my Web.config like this, so this shouldn't be the problem:

```
 <mailSettings>
  <smtp from="MyEmail">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="MyEmail" password="MyEmailPassword" enableSsl="true" />

  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

I have tried answers to alike questions on Stackoverflow like changing the line:

```
 await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
```

to

```
UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
```

But that did not work. I also allowed low security apps to send e-mail to my account. I also tried setting `deliveryMethod="Network"` under my smtp tag but that also did not help.

What could be the problem for not receiving the reset e-mail?

Answer (score 2):

Gmail smtp doesn't send email until you give access to low secure app and enable email forwarding protocol.

After enabling email forwarding (POP) you should get email from google saying someone trying to send email like message and from the mail you can enable low secure app to send email through gmail.

Comment: Yes I know about that. That option is already on. I also did not get that email anymore, since it's already on for a functionality on my website I implemented earlier.